# python How to handle grpc stream after stream cancel() is called

Tags: python, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to write a python client to terminate a gRPC stream

Proto:

```
rpc Start (StartParameters) returns (stream Progress) {}
```

In the client when I'm ready to terminate the stream, I tried calling stream.cancel() and then when I print the events of the captured stream, it doesn't print the events. I see the exception

```
<_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.CANCELLED
    details = "Locally cancelled by application!"
    debug_error_string = "None"
```

client.py

```
stream = self.stub.Start(params)
time.sleep(120)
stream.cancel()

for event in stream:
    print(event)
```

Can somebody please help me with a python code to cancel this stream and print the events in the stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're cancelling the stream before you actually begin iterating over it. Try cancelling the RPC asynchronously, on another thread.

```py
stream = self.stub.Start(params)

def _cancel_after_a_while():
    time.sleep(120)
    stream.cancel()

cancellation_thread = threading.Thread(target=_cancel_after_a_while)
cancellation_thread.start()

for event in stream:
    print(event)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, and that helps

Comment: This still leads to the exception being raised if the client cancels the stream. Is putting the for loop in a try/catch block the intended use (as mentioned in [this example](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/grpc/grpc/+/HEAD/examples/python/cancellation/))? Seems a bit rough that there isn't a more elegant way to cancel a stream.